# Booting on a x64 machine with BIOS?

Tags: kernel, grub2, gentoo, initramfs, bios

I have a *packard bell ze7* it's a x64 machine and it only has BIOS.

Before I got it, I thought that's a non-existent combination...

I'm building Gentoo by hand, my own initramfs, all that good stuff. I've done it before a couple of times(successfully), and as it's not a sufficient number, I'm not sure if I'm doing everything correctly. The reason I'm asking -- I haven't done it with BIOS and I haven't used GRUB, and I'm getting an error. I'm booting from grub prompt(because it doesn't boot by itself for some reason): `set root..`,`linux ...`, `boot`. And I'm getting *"Kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init!" (Code: Bad RIP value)*

So I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the machine being x64 and having only BIOS at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86-64 CPUs, from both AMD and Intel, pre-date UEFI, so it was common for a while to see 64-bit systems with only old-style BIOSs. It is still possible to boot them, with new kernels, so it should be possible to boot your Packard Bell.

I can’t guarantee that your failure is unrelated, but it could easily be related to something else. Attempting to kill `init` means it’s booted far enough to start `init`...

Comment: why then the table at https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2 (pc there means bios) says it's only possible on 32-bit?

Comment: Because you use the i386 version of GRUB2 to boot from the BIOS, even if you’re booting a 64-bit kernel. (The PC I’m writing this from now is a 64-bit PC which boots from BIOS using GRUB2.)